# Can a country restrict the usage of public domain material under the Berne Convention?

Tags: copyright, european-union, public-domain

Some European countries have restrictions on use of public domain content, usually in the form of "cultural heritage" laws. These laws require the payment to institutions or libraries for commercial use of PD material. Doesn't that violate the Berne Convention, or the copyright standards of the European Union?

Comment: I only know of one country that has that: UK and only for Peter Pan.

Comment: Payment to whom? If it is payment to the government, it is simply a tax which is something that copyright law doesn't purport to regulate. Also, what kind of use? Paying to see a painting in a museum or to enter a building isn't a copyright issue, it is a property rights issue.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a law?  My guess is that it is separate from copyright, but without an example it's hard to tell.

Comment: @phoog [Peter Pan](https://www.gosh.org/about-us/peter-pan/copyright/) has a unique, permanent copyright in the UK to benefit a singular children's hospital in the Copyright Act: https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/part/VII/crossheading/provisions-for-the-benefit-of-the-hospital-for-sick-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The U.S. Supreme Court, interpreting a different, much later, copyright treaty that provided copyright protection to works whose copyrights had expired in the U.S. but were still valid in other countries, held in 2012 that:

> The text of the Copyright Clause does not exclude application of
> copyright protection to works in the public domain.

*Golan v. Holder*, [565 U.S. 302](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/565/302/), 318 (2012).

If affording copyright protections to works in the public domain were prohibited by the [Berne Convention](https://www.wipo.int/treaties/en/ip/berne/), in a manner that still had force and effect, this issue would have been raised in *Golan v. Holder*, but it was not, because it is not prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

### Sure, they are sovereign.

A sovereign can declare any law they want and that is not voilating the rights they enshringed. And the UK has a very specific law for one particular work that has royalties to be paid **despite** being in the public domain: The United Kingdom put [Peter Pan](https://www.gosh.org/about-us/peter-pan/copyright/) under a special subsection of their [Copyright Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/part/VII/crossheading/provisions-for-the-benefit-of-the-hospital-for-sick-children) that reads:

> The provisions of [Schedule 6](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/schedule/6) have effect for conferring on GOSH Children's Charity for the benefit of Great Ormond Street Hospital for Children a right to a royalty in respect of the public performance, commercial publication or communication to the public of the play “Peter Pan” by Sir James Matthew Barrie, or of any adaptation of that work, **notwithstanding that copyright in the work expired on 31st December 1987.**

Schedule 6 is a whole section of the law dealing with that one work, and which works and performances need to pay a special royalty to the children's hospital at Great Ormond Street.

Comment: Did it ever enter the public domain, or did it just have its date extended?

Comment: @ohwilleke tricky... I actually can't tell, but that in the UK you will have to pay royalties for as long as that one hospital operates independently and is a children's hospital.